# Mongoose update field in an array of object with dynamic user input

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here is my schema:

```
const arr = [
  {
    oneRepMax: Number,
    date: Date,
  },
];

const dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  "Bench Press": arr,
  Squat: arr,
});
```

this is what my data looks like in mongoose:

```
{     
      "_id":{"$oid":"61e1717705cfbe66dfbc17a4"},
      "Bench Press":[
            {"oneRepMax":{"$numberDouble":"-55.38461538461539"},"date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1641128013201"}},"_id":{"$oid":"61e1724dec6029cd4b45a0ac"}},
            {"oneRepMax":{"$numberDouble":"42.35294117647059"},"date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1642165193866"}},"_id":{"$oid":"61e173c93ce600a1264d07e5"}}
       ],
       "Squat":[],
       "__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}
}
```

How could I update the oneRepMax of the second element in the bench press array for example?

I also want to use my variable `exerciseId`. So it updates the right array

Here is what I have tried:
this works just fine but I am using "Bench Press" as a hard coded value.

```
const newData = await DataModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: userId },
  { $set: { "Bench Press.$[el].oneRepMax": oneRepMax } }, <- Hard coded value
  {
       arrayFilters: [{ "el._id": dataWhereDateIsToday._id }],
       new: true,
  }
  );
   console.log("newData", newData);
```

I am looking to use the exerciseId variable (Which could be "Bench Press" or "Squat")in my query.

Many thanks.

Comment: did you find an answer to your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: I actually thought there was a way, and wasted almost a day on it.. thanks for the reply buddy...